# How to render many images on a cube side and define their position like a gallery wall?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to build a gallery wall via three.js. So far I succeeded rendering an image on each side like this:

[image: paintings on each side]

I've put paintings on left and right. However, I want to render more images on each wall rather than filling the entire wall with a single image. Something like this:

[image: multiple paintings on the wall]

How can I set arbitrary positions?

Here's my code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene() 
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1,1000) 
    console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) 
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer() 
    renderer.setSize(   window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight) 
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement) 
    //keep object in view when resize window 
    window.addEventListener('resize',   () => {
        let width = window.innerWidth
        let height = window.innerHeight
        renderer.setSize(width, height) 
        camera.aspect = width / height
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    }) 
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
    controls.enableZoom = false
    controls.enableRotate = true
    controls.enablePan = false

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2.5, 2, 4 )

    var cubeDice = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x666666, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x666666, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x999999, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x999999, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/h5_1993.132.jpg'), side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/unnamed.png'), side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
    ]

    // var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true } ) 
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(cubeDice)
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,material ) 
    scene.add( cube ) 

    // //set camera closer 
    camera.position.z = 1
    var update = function(){ 
        cube.rotation.y += .005
    } 
    var render = function(){ renderer.render(scene, camera) } 
    var GameLoop = () => { 
        requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop)
        update()
        render() 
    } 
    GameLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MeshFaceMaterial does not do what you want. It makes each image fill up an entire face (an entire wall).

To make separate, movable images on the wall, it would be better to make an individual smaller mesh for each image, and then position them very close to the wall. That way the image can cover the entire mesh, but not cover the entire wall:

[image: layout of meshes]

Comment: thanks ! I just got that right after post ... wandering if there's some other solution.